# Prove that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ke^{-k^2x^2}}{\pi}h(x) = h(0)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

Prove that

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ke^{-k^2x^2}}{\pi}h(x) \, dx= h(0) \tag{A}$$

*Proof*

From the left side of (A)

$$ \frac{k}{\pi}\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-k^2x^2}h(x)\, dx$$

Integration by parts?

$$ \frac{k}{\pi}\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-k^2x^2}h(x)\, dx =  
\frac{k}{\pi}\lim_{k \to \infty} \left[
\left( \int e^{-k^2x^2} \right)h(x)\bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty} +
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int e^{-k^2x^2} \right)h'(x)\, dx \right]$$

But here there's no antiderivative for the Gaussian-type function, unless I can apply those limits of integration to it, but I don't see how. The definite integral of that piece would be $\sqrt{\pi}/{k}. $

Then we'd have

$$ \frac{k}{\pi}\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-k^2x^2}h(x)\, dx =  
\frac{k}{\pi}\lim_{k \to \infty} \left[
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{{k}}h(x)\bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty} +
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int e^{-k^2x^2} \right)h'(x)\, dx \right]$$

Don't know where to go from here. The actual question is to prove that the kernel in the integrand in (A) is Dirac Delta sequence.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $h$? Just integrable? Or continuous as well?

Comment: You cannot factor the dummy parameter $k$ from the limit.

Comment: Oh yep, mistake.

Comment: This is not correct as written. Take $h(x)= c$ then the limit is $\frac{c}{\sqrt{\pi}} = \frac{h(0)}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. Change the denominator to $\sqrt{\pi}$ and you are good

Answer (score 4):

If $h\in C^{0}(-\infty,\infty)\cap L^{\infty}(-\infty,\infty)$, then 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^{2}}(h(u/k)-h(0))du\rightarrow 0,~~~~k\rightarrow\infty
\end{align*}
because $h(u/k)\rightarrow h(0)$ for every $u$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$ and $|h(u/k)-h(0)|\leq 2\|u\|_{L^{\infty}(-\infty,\infty)}$ and $e^{-u^{2}}\in L^{1}(-\infty,\infty)$, so Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Now use the fact that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^{2}}du=\sqrt{\pi}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^{2}}h(u/k)du\rightarrow h(0),~~~~k\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align*}
For the question, let $u=kx$ for the substitution. If the denominator in question is $\pi$, then it may not go through.

Comment: You beat me to it.  (+1) Of course, the tacit assumption is that $h$ is continuous.